# Meteor template query change, how to change the content from the database?

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor

I am working on a blog with meteor and I have got to the search portion: now I would like to change the data going to the template variables according to the search criteria. As of now there I don't understand how to make the data that is going to be rendered in the template re-sort.

Here is what I have now:
**HTML**

```
<template name="posts">
   {{#each post}}
     <div class = "postWrapper">
     <p>{{postTitle}} - <small><em>{{userName}}<em></small></p>
     <p><small>{{postDate}}</small><p>
     <div class="postText">{{safe 'postText'}}</div>
     <br/>
     </div>
   {{/each}}
</template>
```

**Javascript**

```
Template.posts.post = function(){
   return TestPosts.find({}, {sort: {timeStamp: -1}, limit: 100});
}
```

How do I change the Template.posts.post query so that it sorts by somthing other than timestamp. Any changes I make to the Template.posts.post query ends up being nothing when the event is fired.

```
  Template.searchForm.events = {
    "click .cancelBtn": function(){
       $("#lightbox-container, #searchForm, #postForm").hide();
    },
    "click #searchBtn": function(){
        var reply = TestPosts.find({}, {sort: {timeStamp: 1}});
            //what do I need here to be able to change the posts returned 
            //to the template?
    }
  }
```

I tried to use meteor.render but it did nothing. Any guidance would be great.

Answer (score 1):

you will want to start thinking more "reactively", rather than procedurally. If it helps, reactive thinking is a bit like declarative thinking. Just declare what you want to see and let Meteor figure out the how and when.

With that in mind, this might work for you (making the sort order a session variable):

```
Session.setDefault('sortOrder', {'timestamp': -1});
Template.posts.post = function(){
   return TestPosts.find({}, {sort: Session.get('sortOrder'), limit: 100});
}

Template.searchForm.events = {
  "click .cancelBtn": function(){
     $("#lightbox-container, #searchForm, #postForm").hide();
  },
  "click #searchBtn": function(){
      Session.set('sortOrder', {'timestamp': 1});
  }
}
```

Comment: I had not thought of it like this, this changes a lot. Thank you for your time.